# Biztalk 2010 : Not able to Query SalesForece through Enterprise WSDL.Illegal Header issue

Tags: wsdl, salesforce, integration, biztalk

I am implementing BizTalk 2010 Saleforce integration where I am purely using enterprise wsdl for calling its methods. No C# code for any operation.

I am successfully able to call login method and getting result back with all details. Now at the subsequent request where I am calling query method which does not take additional parameter for taking header. It is only taking query string as parameter shown below.

```
<element name='query'>
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
        <element name='queryString' type='string' />
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
  </element>
```

Now the problem is when I am calling this method it is giving me error for "Invalid Session and Illegal Session Header" because no header getting passed.

Alternative that I tried is constructing message and passing header with session id (taking from login result) explicitly as shown below.

```
Option 1.

varXMLDocument = new System.Xml.XmlDocument(); 
varXMLDocument.LoadXml("<ns0:Envelope xmlns:ns0='http://QuerySFDCVIAWSDL.QueryRequestSchema'><Body><query><queryString>SELECT "some fields xyz..." FROM Quote</queryString></query></Body></ns0:Envelope>");

msgSendQryToSalesforce = varXMLDocument;

//Setting  Header
msgSendQryToSalesforce(WCF.Headers) = "<ns0:SessionHeader xmlns:ns0=\"urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com\"><ns0:sessionId>" + SessionId + "</ns0:sessionId></ns0:SessionHeader>";

Option 2.

//Creating session header in same xml.
varXMLDocument.LoadXml("<ns0:Envelope xmlns:ns0='http://QuerySFDCVIAWSDL.QueryRequestSchema'><Header><SessionHeader><sessionId>"+SessionId+"</sessionId></SessionHeader></Header><Body><query><queryString>SELECT "some fields xyz..." FROM Quote</queryString></query></Body></ns0:Envelope>");
```

The problem with these approach is SessionHeader getting removed at runtime and only querystring getting  passed to SFDC. Hence getting same result "Invalid Session and Illegal Session Header".

//Request From Orchestration Debugger where there is no session header after been passed explicitly, it is only taking querystring.

```
//Final Request
<ns0:query xmlns:ns1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:ns0="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com"><ns0:queryString>SELECT "some fields xyz..." FROM Quote</ns0:queryString></ns0:query>
```

Can anybody please help me and assist me in finding out the appropriate solution so that at all subsequent request have session ids passed in session header.

From SoapUI tool when I am passing same xml with session header it is getting me result back.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>     
      <urn:SessionHeader>         <urn:sessionId>some id.......</urn:sessionId>
      </urn:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:query>
         <urn:queryString>Select "some fields xyz..." from Quote</urn:queryString>
      </urn:query>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Not able to understand why from BizTalk it is not working.

Just FYI my queryRequestSchema

```
Just FYI my queryRequestSchema

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://QuerySFDCVIAWSDL.QueryRequestSchema" xmlns="http://QuerySFDCVIAWSDL.QueryRequestSchema" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Envelope">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Header">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="SessionHeader">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="sessionId" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Body">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="query">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="queryString" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **(WCF.CustomOutboundHeaders)** context property.

Replace this line:

```
//Setting  Header
msgSendQryToSalesforce(WCF.Headers) = "<ns0:SessionHeader xmlns:ns0=\"urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com\"><ns0:sessionId>" + SessionId + "</ns0:sessionId></ns0:SessionHeader>";
```

With this

```
// Setting Header
msgSendQryToSalesforce(WCF.OutboundCustomHeaders) = "<ns0:SessionHeader xmlns:ns0=\"urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com\"><ns0:sessionId>" + SessionId + "</ns0:sessionId></ns0:SessionHeader>";
```

If you're using a utilities class, it might be a good idea to store that header template in a public const string variable, or write a method to format it for you - assuming you'll be sending multiple messages to Salesforce, you'll be able to reuse it more easily:

```
msgSendQryToSalesforce(WCF.OutboundCustomHeaders) = Utilities.GetSalesforceHeader(SessionId);
```

and in your utilities class, have a method like

```
public static string GetSalesforceHeader(string sessionId)
{
    return "<ns0:SessionHeader xmlns:ns0=\"urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com\"><ns0:sessionId>" + sessionId + "</ns0:sessionId></ns0:SessionHeader>";
}
```

More information on setting SOAP headers in Orchestrations:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb246026.aspx (but note that you don't actually have to use an XmlDocument for this); this applies to 2010 even though it says its for 2013.

Comment: WCF.OutboundCustomHeaders worked for me. Thank you all appreciate your responses.

Comment: Great.  If you don't mind, mark this as the answer so future users will be able to find it more easily.  Thanks.